# InfoPath drop down list showing old values

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

Currently I have changed the values of a drop down list in my Infopath form from 2012 dates to 2013 dates. When I view the changes in designer the changes are there when I open the form in filler or open the published form in sharepoint it still shows the 2012 dates. The drop down list option are manually entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having is the drop down list was on two separate views and wasn't changing the values on both views. If having this issue make sure you don't have buttons changing a view on you without you knowing it.